# Can't delete item from recyclerview realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to set a method to delete an item from firebase Realtime database permanently and for some reason i keep getting an error which says "getRef" doesn't exist, although a lot of people use the same method to delete items, I've tried to read and try solutions from multiple articles but it's not really working, this is my code for the adapter class where the error is:

```
public class AdminAdapterCalories extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdminAdapterCalories.MYViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<Calories> nlist;
    public AdminAdapterCalories(ArrayList<Calories> nlist){
        this.nlist=nlist;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MYViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.admin_card_calorie,parent,false);
        return new MYViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MYViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.food.setText(nlist.get(position).getName());
        holder.calories.setText("Calories : "+nlist.get(position).getCalories());
        holder.proteins.setText("Proteins : "+nlist.get(position).getProteins());
        Picasso.get().load(nlist.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.imge);
        holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(holder.imge.getContext());
                builder.setTitle("Delete Panel");
                builder.setMessage("Are You Sure You Want To Delete?");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Food")
                                .child(getRef(position).getkey()).removeValue();
                    }
                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    }
                });

                builder.show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return nlist.size();
    }

    class MYViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView food,calories,proteins;
        ImageView imge,edit,delete;

        public MYViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            food= itemView.findViewById(R.id.food_card_admn);
            calories=itemView.findViewById(R.id.caloiries_admin);
            proteins=itemView.findViewById(R.id.proteins_admin);
            imge=itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image_card_admin);

            delete=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.IvD);
        }
    }
}
```

the error is in this line `.child(getRef(position).getkey()).removeValue();`
I've also tried to put instead of that `child(getitemid(position).removevalue();`

The model class calories is:

```
public class Calories {
   private String Calories,Name,Proteins,Image;

    public Calories() {
    }

    public Calories(String calories, String name, String proteins,String image) {
        Calories = calories;
        Name = name;
        Proteins = proteins;
        Image=image;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return Image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.Image = image;
    }

    public String getCalories() {
        return Calories;
    }

    public void setCalories(String calories) {
        Calories = calories;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getProteins() {
        return Proteins;
    }

    public void setProteins(String proteins) {
        Proteins = proteins;
    }
}
```

This is what the database looks like [image]
this is how I generate the id
[image]

Comment: Can you share more of the error stacktrace? With this it is not clear about the exception being thrown.

Comment: @Anand there is no except i just get the error before executing which is:Cannot resolve method'getRef'

Comment: getResf()  is not predefined method.you only need to pass "key" to delete.@john

Comment: how can i pass it? whenever i search for the key thing they always use getref to get it @androidLearner

Comment: Do you store the key as a member variable in `Calories` class ?

Comment: do you mean the id? no i dont ill update the queestion with the Calories class

Comment: You need to store this key/id as a field in `Calories` and use it when you delete the value >>

Comment: Are the keys something like a sequence 01, 02, 03, .... ?

Comment: yes i add them manually through some add data class

Comment: but i want to delete the item when i click delete icon that's next to the item in recycler view

Comment: @Zain i edited it to show how i add the id

Comment: @john please check UPDATE section in answer to get those ids in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store item ids using a member variable in `Calories`, and create getter & setter for it.

```
public class Calories {

   private String id;
   public String getId() {return id;}
   public String setId(String id) {this.id = id;}
//....
```

Then get this id for the item that you need to deleted when it's selected in the `RecyclerView` like:

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        String id = nlist.get(position).getId();
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Food")
                .child(id).removeValue();
    }
});
```

**UPDATE:**

As you set keys manually on firebase console, so you can get them whenever you grab the list of `Food` from firebase using a `ValueEventListener`

And get the key of each item using `getKey()` method:

```
List<Calories> caloryList = new ArrayList();

ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                
            for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String id = singleSnapshot.getKey();
                Calories calory = singleSnapshot.getValue(Calories.class);
                calory.setId(id);
                caloryList.add(calory);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
};

DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Food");
ref.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

Eventually `caloryList` should be passed to the `RecyclerView` adapter.

Comment: i tried doing this and they gave me the following error when i tried to delete `java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(DatabaseReference.java:96)
        at net.smallacademy.authenticatorapp.AdminAdapterCalories$1$1.onClick(AdminAdapterCalories.java:55)`

Comment: @john it means that `id` is `null`, Did you set ids on `Calories` objects within `nlist` .. this should also map in the corresponding firebase database

Comment: no i didnt because the id isnt an edittext or something it doesnt have a ,name like calories proteins etc so i dont know

Comment: How you generate these ids on firebase like `01`, `02`... ? when you do that you need to set them to `Calories` objects before saving them into firebase database

Comment: @john you can try for instance to use `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Food")           .child("01").removeValue();` and then check that this item is deleted on firebase console

Comment: i know this method but i want item to be deleted when i click on the delete icon no matter what item not just the 01

Answer (score 0):

```
  //First get key before store data in database.
    
    String key = mDatabaseRef.child("Food").push().getKey();
    
    //store this key in model class for later use.(delete)
    
    yourModelClass.setMyKey(key);
    yourModelClass.set(allOtherValues);
    
    //then store in database.
    
    mDatabase.child("Food").child(key).setValue(yourModelClass);
    
    //then delete data using "key".
    
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Food")
                                    
   .child(yourModelClass.getMyKey()).removeValue();

    //getMyKey() is just getter method returns stored key.
```