# Firebase Deleting A Value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an app with Android Studio using Firebase. I want to delete a certain date but when I click on the delete button it does nothing. I can't reach to parent because it's a generated key. Any help would be appreciated.

```
private void deleteDate(){
    String dateValue = showDate.getText().toString();

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String userid = user.getUid();

    DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userid).child("smokeFreeDays");

    usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot userDataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                String date = userDataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                if (date.equals(dateValue)) {
                    snapshot.getRef().child(dateValue).removeValue();
                } else if (!date.equals(dateValue)) {
                    snapshot.getRef().child(dateValue).removeValue();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {
            Log.w("tag", "loadPost:onCancelled", error.toException());
        }
    });
}
```

My Database:

[image]

Comment: If you log `dateValue` what does it output? Please edit your question to include the updated code and its output.

Comment: [Check here to delete ]<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67653570/cant-delete-item-from-recyclerview-realtime-database/67654265#67654265>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment above for debugging the issue.

But as an overall hint, I'd recommend reconsidering the data structure under `smokeFreeDays` to look like this:

```
"smokeFreeDays": {
  "2021-05-09": true,
  "2021-05-10": true
}
```

The two changes in this structure:

- The date format is now ordered `year-month-day`, which is better suited for querying. For example, you can get all smoke free days in 2021 with: `usersRef.orderByKey().startAt("2021-").endAt("2021~")`.
- We now use the date as the key, which means we no longer have to load all `smokeFreeDays` to find the value to delete. You can now delete the node once you know the date with: `usersRef.child("2021-05-09").removeValue()`.