# Deleting data from database

Tags: java, android

In Firebase RealtimeDatabase, I'm saving chats in "Chats" reference like that:

"Chats" :
{
"-**Ma83vy-1hjQ8nJ6LgTM**" : {
"isseen" : true,
"message" : "Go",
"messageTime" : "14:20",
"receiver" : "to",
"sender" : "from"
},
"-**Ma845xcxQjN5IlhpaPV**" : {
"isseen" : true,
"message" : "Hi",
"messageTime" : "14:21",
"receiver" : "to",
"sender" : "whom"
},

[image]

WHen I want delete a specific chat, I need to obtain this: **Ma83vy-1hjQ8nJ6LgTM** or this
**Ma83vy1hjQ8nJ6LgTM**. But I don't know how to get this.

This is how I save chats in database:

DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

```
    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

    hashMap.put("sender", sender);
    hashMap.put("receiver", receiver);
    hashMap.put("message", message);
    hashMap.put("messageTime", time);
    hashMap.put("isseen", false);

    reference.child("Chats").push().setValue(hashMap);
```

So how can get these headers : **Ma83vy-1hjQ8nJ6LgTM** or **Ma845xcxQjN5IlhpaPV**
Or is there any other way of deleting a specific data ?

Comment: [please check here to delete node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67653570/cant-delete-item-from-recyclerview-realtime-database/67654265#67654265)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38232140/how-to-get-the-key-from-the-value-in-firebase/38232280#38232280